# How to implement dicts / sets opposed to a list search, to increase speed

Tags: python, list, search

I am making a program that has to search through very long lists, and I have seen people suggesting that using sets and dicts speeds it up massively. However, I am at a loss as to how to make it work within my code. Currently, the program does this:

```
indexes = []

print("Collecting indexes...")
for term in sliced_5:
    indexes.append(hex_crypted.index(term))
```

The code searches through the hex_crypted list, which contains 1,000,000+ terms, finds the index of the term, and then appends it to the the 'indexes' list.

I simply need to speed this process. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Without knowing more about what you do with your data, it's difficult to make pertinent suggestions...

Comment: Please provide some sample of input and output, and preferably a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to build a lookup table so you don't need to repeatedly loop over `hex_crypted`. Then you can simply look up each term in the table.

```
print("Collecting indexes...")
lookup = {term: index for (index, term) in enumerate(hex_crypted)}
indexes = [lookup[term] for term in sliced_5]
```

Comment: Thankyou, this worked perfectly, and it works incredibly fast now!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method if you have a list is to do a set function on the list to return it as a set, but I don't think that is what you want to do in this case.

```
hex_crypted_set = set(hex_crypted)
```

If you need to keep that index for some reason, you'll want to instead build a dictionary first.

```py
hex_crypted_dict = {}
for i in enumerate(hex_crypted):
    hex_crypted_dict[i[1]] = i[0]
```

And then to get that index you just search the dict:

```py
indexes = []
for term in sliced_5:
    indexes.append(hex_crypted_dict[term])
```

You will end up with the appropriate indexes which correspond to the original long list and only iterate that long list one time, which will be a lot better performance than iterating it for every time you do a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to generate a dict, for example:

```py
hex_crypted_dict = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(hex_crypted)}
```

Then your code changed to

```
indexes = []
hex_crypted_dict = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(hex_crypted)}

print("Collecting indexes...")
for term in sliced_5:
    indexes.append(hex_crypted_dict[term])
```